# replaceAll() method doesn't replace 2 matched strings if they are placed directly one after another

Tags: java

I want to erase words "makbet" in my string, but my method deleteAllStopWords() is working really strange: if my string is " makbet makbet ", after I use my method string "makbet" is created.

I called deleteAllStopWords() twice for one string and then for string " makbet makbet " method is working as expected, but problem is with string " makbet makbet makbet makbet " (string "makbet" is returned). When I invoked method thrice the problem is with string " makbet makbet makbet makbet makbet makbet makbet makbet ".

The stopWords variable is ArrayList that have "makbet" inside.

```
private String removeSpecialChars(String word) {
    if (word.matches(".*\\[.*\\]"))
        word = deleteAnnotation(word);

    if (word.isEmpty())
        return word;

    char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
    char lastChar = word.charAt(word.length() - 1);

    while (lastChar == '.' || lastChar == ','
            || lastChar == ';' || lastChar == ')'
            || lastChar == ']' || lastChar == '}'
            || lastChar == '-' || lastChar == '?'
            || lastChar == '\"' || lastChar == '!'
            || lastChar == ',' || lastChar == ':'
            || lastChar == '|') {
        word = removeCharAt(word, word.length() - 1);

        if (!word.isEmpty())
            lastChar = word.charAt(word.length() - 1);
    }

    if (firstChar == '{' || firstChar == '[' || firstChar == '(' || firstChar == '\"') {
        word = removeCharAt(word, 0);
    }

    return word;
}

private String deleteAllStopWords(String txt) {
    String ret = " ";
    for (String word : txt.split("\\s")) {
        if (word.isEmpty())
            continue;

        word = removeSpecialChars(word);
        ret += word + " ";
    }

    for (String word : stopWords) {
        ret = ret.replaceAll(" (?i)" + word + " ", " ");
    }

    return ret;
}


     public static void main()
     {
             String txt = " makbet makbet ";
             txt = deleteAllStopWords(txt);
             System.out.println(txt);        //prints "makbet"
             txt = deleteAllStopWords(txt);
             System.out.println(txt);        //prints ""
     }
```

Of course that 2 methods are inside my class, I deleted unnecessery code for better readability.

Comment: If you could post some examples of: Input, Actual Output, Desired Output and your `main` method where you call `deleteAllStopWords()` it would be better for us to understand and provide help

Comment: @Frakcool Thank you for responding. I'm sorry that my previous code wasn't clear. I edited my question, hope that it is be more proper now.

Comment: So, by caling `deleteAllStopWords` once should print `""`? Also post what `stopWords` contains. Or better post a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I got it right, "makbet" is in your "stopWords" and you want it to be deleted from the string.

So, the reason why it doesn't work for you is that you are trying to delete it with spaces. When you replace `" makbet "` in `" makbet makbet "`, it finds the first match and removes it, the string left is `"makbet "`, without space at the beginning. At the second iteration, you create a new string with space at the beginning and finally get what you need.

If you need to replace all `makbet` at once, I'd make spaces optional in regex string (`\\s?`) or replace all `makbet` without spaces and remove double spaces afterwards.